# CompletableFuture.supplyAsync with executor works slower than without

Tags: concurrency, future, completable-future

I am using a custom ThreadTaskExecutor for parallelizing the pageable process of Elasticsearch index filling.

This custom ThreadTaskExecutor runs all tasks using "invokeAll" method based on the newFixedThreadPool call with configuration.

```
public <T> List<T> execute(final List<Callable<T>> tasks, final Integer threadsNumber) {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadsNumber);

    try {
        List<Future<T>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(wrapWithMDCContext(tasks));
        while (true) {
            boolean allPagesImported = futures.stream().allMatch(Future::isDone);

            if (allPagesImported) {
                return futures.stream().map(future -> {
                    try {
                        return future.get();
                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                        log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                    }

                    return null;
                })
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }

            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(STATUS_CHECK_INTERVAL_SECONDS);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    return Collections.emptyList();
}

private <T> List<Callable<T>> wrapWithMDCContext(final List<Callable<T>> tasks) {
    Map<String, String> contextMap = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();

    return tasks.stream()
            .map(task -> (Callable<T>) () -> {
                if (nonNull(contextMap)) {
                    MDC.setContextMap(contextMap);
                }

                return task.call();
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Each task contains:

- one CompletableFuture.supplyAsync call without executor as the second parameter.
- call of the future.join();

  ```
    private ImportPageResult importPageUnsafe(final ImportPageParameters importPageParameters) {
    // some preparation for indexing process

    CompletableFuture<Boolean> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        if (nonNull(contextMap)) {
            MDC.setContextMap(contextMap);
        }

        boolean isSuccessful = true;

        // Elasticseatch index filling

        isSuccessful = index(SomeIndexModel.class, someIndexModelData);

        return isSuccessful;
    }); // supplyAsync without executor; approximately twice slower in case we are using Executors.newFixedThreadPool() for example

    warmUpCache();

    Boolean isSuccessful = future.join();

    return ImportPageResult.of(isSuccessful);
  ```

  }

In the scope of the general process, the process works slower where CompletableFuture.supplyAsync used with executor (approximately twice slower) than we use CompletableFuture.supplyAsync used without an executor

Could you please explain why this is going on that way ?

The second side effect: The integration test for testing of process where we are using CompletableFuture.supplyAsync without executor is freezing on CI except for the CompletableFuture.supplyAsync with executor.

Comment: Apparently, your question is is about the second code snippet, while the first has no recognizable relationship to the second. If you are going to `join()` immediately after commencing an asynchronous action, why bother using a `CompletableFuture` at all?

Comment: Hi @Holger, I suppose, the code which CompletableFuture.supplyAsync contains, especially index(SomeIndexModel.class, someIndexModelData); will start working right after supplyAsync will be created. This "index" functionality should be almost finished before the feature.join() in a separate thread, meanwhile warmUpCache() functionality should be worked in the current thread. Probably, if I am correct,  that was the main thing in this functionality.

Comment: But since `warmUpCache()` seems to have no relationship to the operation whose result you need and doesn’t return a value, it would make more sense to run `warmUpCache()` asynchronously, as then, you can perform the operation whose result you need right in the current thread and return its result, without waiting for `warmUpCache()` to finish.

Comment: The warmUpCache() it's just a cache evict and this operation is almost free, if we are talking about time costs, instead of index() operation which is located in CompletableFuture.supplyAsync. In general, your proposal does not solve the main problem - CompletableFuture.supplyAsync with executor as the second parameter works slower than without executor

Comment: Then, there’s even less reason to use an asynchronous operation at all. You submit it, perform an operation which “is almost free” and `join`, so it’s effectively not asynchronous at all. But of course, when you needlessly create another thread pool for an effectively synchronous operation, it has a higher overhead than using the already existing default pool. That’s expected and simply not, how thread pools are supposed to be used. You still didn’t explain the relationship between these two code snippets, but the first has the same problem (plus misunderstandings about how `invokeAll` works).